# MVC3 Razor View Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-sql, razor

I just started to learn MVC3. Have been coding in traditional ASP.NET For a while and now would like to move to MVC.

Some things that i don't understand (probably just been used differently then in traditional ASP.NET)

I'm trying to write a simple news module that will display news and allow to insert comment for them.

So first step is, i created a tables on my SQL server:
TblNews
TblCategories
TblComments

Created Linq2SQL data Class in Models folder and named it News.dbml
Created Controller HomeController.cs and a method called Index() in it.
Look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Models.NewsDataContext db = new Models.NewsDataContext();
            var Model = (from n in db.TblNews
                         select new
                         {
                             ID = n.ID,
                             Title = n.Title,
                             Description = n.Description,
                             Category = n.TblCategory.CategoryName
                         });

            return View(Model);
        }
```

As you see I'm trying to select all the news and their category names (TblNews and TblCategories do have relationship between them)

After that I'm returning the data that i got from the query.

In the View i have:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "News Index Page";
}

<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                ID: @item.ID<br />
                Title: @item.Title<br />
                Description: @item.Description<br />
                Category: @item.Category
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Which should return something like:

```
ID: 4
Title: asd
Description: asd
Category: 2
```

That's my sample data from tables.

When i run the page it gives me error message:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'ID'
```

but when i focus my mouse on "item" variable it actually contain:

```
{ ID = 4, Title = asd, Description = asd, Category = Test2 }
```

I also tried to return Linq Query as list by adding .ToList() to the end of it.

Can anybody give me any hints and get me into the right direction?

Sorry if i explained something incorrectly. English is not my primary language.
Please ask if you need any more information.

Thank you very much.

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your model declaration at the top of your view so will default to type `object`. When you do `item.ID` you're doing `object.ID`, which is why it complains that `object` does not contain a definition for `ID`

Add the following:

```
@model List<Models.NewsDataContext>
```

Also, make sure you **evaluate** the LINQ query by calling `.ToList()` before your return Model, that way the query is already executed against the database before it hits the view:

```
return View(Model.ToList());
```

**Edit:** Actually, in your LINQ query you are selecting into an anonymous type, **you must use a concrete class in order to use this in your view**. The below assumes your `TblNews` corresponds to a class called `News`:

```
var Model = (from n in db.TblNews
                     select new News //class name here
                     {
                         ID = n.ID,
                         Title = n.Title,
                         Description = n.Description,
                         Category = n.TblCategory.CategoryName
                     });

        return View(Model.ToList());
```

Then change your model to:

```
@model List<News>
```

Comment: @user2110925 Ah you'll need to select into in `TblNews` class in your linq statement, change it to `select new TblNews` (or whatever that class is called), then change your model to `List<TblNews>` (or whatever that class is called)

Comment: I don't really understand this part about a class that i should correspond to. o_O

How can i find this out?
My table name is TblNews but i don't really understand about that class thing.

in traditional ASP.NET I never had to use a type for tables, i had to use them only when i was populating a dropdownlist or something like that.

Now I'm really confused... :(

Comment: @user2110925 I think your class is `TblNews`. Basically, in your `NewsDataContext`, you will have a `DbSet<TblNews>` yeah? That means that you should use the `TblNews` class. This isn't specific to MVC, it is specific to using an ORM such as entity framework, linq to sql, nhibernate etc.

Comment: Why would i have DbSet<TblNews> in my NewsDataContext if I'm using Linq to SQL Data Class Module?

That's something that i don't understand...

Comment: @user2110925 Ah sorry, you'll definitely have a class that corresponds to the table though. It's the `TblNews` class. Use that.

Comment: All this MVC thing doesn't make any sense to me at all... :(
I tried to use Modules.TblNew as you said and it still doesn't work...I'm tired of all these errors in it. Don't even know is it worth to look into it any further :(